# JavaFX: Draw a rectangle on canvas based on 2 mouse clicks

Tags: java, javafx, canvas, drawing, rectangles

I'm trying to create a program, which should draw a rectangle on a canvas based on two left mouse clicks and clears the canvas with one right click.

The rectangle should be created in a way, where the first mouse click simulates one corner of the rectangle, and the next mouse click simulates the diagonal corner of the rectangle compared to the first mouse click.

I'm stuck on how to store the coordinates for the first mouse click, and then put the second mouse click to good use, as the rectangle per definition is created based on only 1 set of coordinates, which is the upper-left corner of the rectangle.

Right now, all my code does is that it draws fixed sized rectangles (50x25) which obviously isn't what I want. This is just to see if the clearing part works.

This is what I've got so far:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DrawRectangle extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Title");
        Canvas canv = new Canvas(500, 400);
        GraphicsContext gc = canv.getGraphicsContext2D();

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> event = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                    double x = event.getX();
                    double y = event.getY();                    
                    gc.setFill(Color.BLUE);
                    gc.fillRect(x, y, 50, 25);
                }
            }
        };

        canv.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event);

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> event2 = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event2) {
                if (event2.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                gc.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 400);
                }
            }
        };

        canv.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event2);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(canv);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I don't know if it matters which corners of the rectangle the mouse clicks should simulate, maybe someone got any ideas?

Best regards and happy new year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just save the first click point in a member variable, then use it and reset it when the user makes a second click point.

Note: the sample code below uses a [switch expression](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/354) from Java 13+.  If switch expressions are not available in your Java version, convert it to a standard switch statement or if/else clauses.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.*;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DrawRectangle extends Application {

    private static final int W = 500;
    private static final int H = 400;

    private Point2D savedPoint = null;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(W, H);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        canvas.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            switch (event.getButton()) {
                case PRIMARY   -> handlePrimaryClick(gc, event);
                case SECONDARY -> gc.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
            }
        });

        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(canvas), W, H));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void handlePrimaryClick(GraphicsContext gc, MouseEvent event) {
        Point2D clickPoint = new Point2D(event.getX(), event.getY());

        if (savedPoint == null) {
            savedPoint = clickPoint;
        } else {
            Rectangle2D rectangle2D = getRect(savedPoint, clickPoint);

            gc.setFill(Color.BLUE);
            gc.fillRect(
                    rectangle2D.getMinX(),
                    rectangle2D.getMinY(),
                    rectangle2D.getWidth(),
                    rectangle2D.getHeight()
            );

            savedPoint = null;
        }
    }

    private Rectangle2D getRect(Point2D p1, Point2D p2) {
        return new Rectangle2D(
                Math.min(p1.getX(), p2.getX()),
                Math.min(p1.getY(), p2.getY()),
                Math.abs(p1.getX() - p2.getX()),
                Math.abs(p1.getY() - p2.getY())
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you very much - and happy new year! I'm not quite familiar with the switch statements and the syntax where you initialise/instantiate(?) `event` and the use of an `->` at line 22. Is it possible that you could elaborate?

I've made it work with if statements, as those switch statements didn't worked with my Java version.

Comment: I provided a link in the answer on what [switch expressions](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/354) are and what the alternatives are, read it.   The syntax for the event handling of the mouse clicked event is a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), for which I have also linked a tutorial in this comment (especially read the section in the tutorial titled: "Lambda Expressions in GUI Applications").  It is not initializing/instantiating an event (the event was already created by JavaFX), it is defining a handler for relevant events.

Comment: You have been a massive help. Lambda expressions makes the code much more concise, elegant and readable! Thank you.